# How to use JDK GregorianCalendar object dates with Joda

Tags: java, jodatime, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to use Joda library since count periods with Java native methods is a pain in the neck and all my attempts give unprecise results

I have seen this sample to

```
int n = Days.daysBetween(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays();
```

since all my classes manage GregorianCalendar, I need that method that counts the days support GregorianCalendar, something like

```
 public int countDays(GregorianCalendar start, GregorianCalendar end){
     //convert to joda start and end
     ...
     return Days.daysBetween(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays();
 }
```

So my question:
How to convert and reconvert `GregorianCalendar` object to the object managed by Joda without side effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` constructor that takes an `Object`, which can "[include ReadableInstant, String, Calendar and Date.](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(java.lang.Object))" It specifically mentions `GregorianCalendar`, as well.

```
public int countDays(GregorianCalendar gregStart, GregorianCalendar gregEnd) {
    DateTime start = new DateTime(gregStart);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(gregEnd);
    return Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the timezone from the `GragorianCalander` before creating the joda `LocalDate`

Something along these lines:

```
public int countDays(GregorianCalendar start, GregorianCalendar end){

    TimeZone timeZone = start.getTimeZone();
    DateTimeZone jodaTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone.getID());
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(start.getTimeInMillis(), jodaTimeZone);
    LocalDate startDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();

    timeZone = end.getTimeZone();
    jodaTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone.getID());
    dateTime = new DateTime(end.getTimeInMillis(), jodaTimeZone);
    LocalDate endDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();

    return Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
}
```

Comment: You can actually create a JODA `DateTime` directly from a `GregorianCalendar` with `new DateTime(calendar);`

Comment: @DavidConrad well there you go, You can tell I don't really use JodaTime often.